# Apache: How to enable Directory Index browsing at the Doc Root level?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have several web development projects running on Fedora 13. I generally setup Apache to serve my larger projects as Virtual Hosts, but I've got several small projects cycling through that I don't really care to setup a VirtualHost for each one. Instead I'd like them all under a subdirectory of the main VirtualHost entry. I just want Apache to serve me the directory index when I browse to the host name.

For example, the hostname `projects.mydomain.com` refers to `/var/www/projects`, and that directory contains only subdirectories (no index file).

Unfortunately when I browse to the host directly I get:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

But my virtual host entry in my apache config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName      projects.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot        /var/www/projects
    <Directory "/var/www/projects">
        Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5):

Check if there is something like this further down the configuration.
It matches "/" and denies Indexing.

```
  <LocationMatch "^/+$">
        Options -Indexes
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/noindex.html
  </LocationMatch>
```

Comment: Yes, this solved the problem! However, on CentOS 6.6, this part of configuration is located outside of main config file, in sub-direcotry `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
    <Directory />
            Options +FollowSymlinks +Indexes
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
```